# How Google Drive Android API is working even after its shutdown?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

As Google specified:

[image]

Today, I ran an old version of my app and found that Drive Android API is still working!

How is this possible? Has anyone experienced the same thing? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I could imagine the api-service is running on a different server + Google doesn't want older apps using that API to crash.

Comment: So in short, it is there just out of courtesy. They may stop it anytime. Right?

Comment: Just guessing but yeah, I think so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a common practice for Google to keep services available for a fixed amount of time (usually announced) when retiring a service. This has happened years ago with the first version of the Google Maps API, which got retired and replaced. The API was still working up to a year later (that's when I upgraded my application). Can't tell whether that would have worked for longer, but regardless, it's not permanent.

Many times, large companies struggle to upgrade their systems/microservices and Google is well aware that not everyone will meet the official deadline. My assumption here is that in order to ensure everyone can transition at their own pace, without disrupting their services, they just offer the extra grace period until they notice the API calls volume drops below a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks for speaking out of your own experience instead of just guessing.